# twitter bootstrap pagination on Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

[Twitter bootstrap pagination](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#pagination) has an example, but it's not showing how to specify a number of records per page, for example.

> ```
> <div class="pagination">
> <ul>
> <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
> </ul>
> </div>
> ```

Where can I see the detailed information on how to integrate with my page?

There's also nice [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate-revised) with will_paginate gem from Ryan, but I want to give a try for t/bootstrap pagination feature.

Comment: twitter bootstrap only provide you UI for paging component, you have to write your own logic for building pagination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`will_paginate-bootstrap` is a good gem to use for this: https://github.com/nickpad/will_paginate-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks. I've just updated my post that I'm aware of will_paginate. Is it better thant twitter's one?

Comment: They are separate things. There's nothing to compare since they work together. The gem just combines them together.

Comment: Ok. I will try will_paginate then! :)